# How to link with older gdiplus.lib so I can run on older version of windows?

Tags: windows-10, gdi+

My app uses gdiplus.dll and is built with Windows SDK 10.0.18362.0 corresponding to Windows 10 version 1903.  Works fine on that OS version.

When I try to run it on Windows 10 version 1809 it crashes on calls to gdiplus.

Without having a windows 10 version 1809 computer here, can I build it with the older gdiplus so that it will run on OS 1809?   And if the answer is Yes, it would seem that I need to get the older gdiplus.lib and *.h -- but those don't see to be available...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Someone should have answered: in VS2017 just change project settings to build with an earlier version of the windows SDK.

But anyway, that wouldn't have helped because that wasn't the issue.  My bad, the problem was caused because I forgot to call the needed "initialization" call that is required before starting to use GDI+ calls.  It ran on some PCs because another application had called that init code - although its surprising to me that the initialization appears to work across processes in that way....